# Second TextBox showing same Text Selection as first

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-runtime, selection

Long time listener, first time caller here. I'm having a strange issue with the TextBox in WinRT C#/XAML that I hope someone may be able to help me with.

Basically, I'm working on creating a Custom Control that essentially requires **a second TextBox to be a copy of the first, including showing the same Text, and showing the same Selected Text**. Obviously for the Text requirement I simply respond to the TextChanged event on the first TextBox and set the Text of the second TextBox to the Text from the first, which works great.

For the Selected Text requirement I started with a similar solution, and my code for this is as follows:

```
    void TextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextBox2.Select(this.TextBox1.SelectionStart, this.TextBox1.SelectionLength);
    }
```

This seemed to work pretty well when initially used with a mouse:

[image: screen cap using mouse]

But I'm having a problem when selecting text with **Touch**. I double-tap within the TextBox to create the first "anchor" as you do in Touch, then drag to begin the selection; but **I only ever manage to select a single character normally before the selection stops.** The TextBox doesn't lose focus exactly, but the behaviour is similar to that; the selection anchors disappear and I can't continue selecting anything unless I re-double-tap to start a new selection. If I remove the code to select text in TextBox2 then the Touch selection behaves perfectly in TextBox1.

I've been trying to fix this for a while and cannot, I'm not sure if I can get the desired behaviour with WinRT TextBoxes. Does anyone have any ideas? Or perhaps another way to implement a solution with two TextBoxes with this behaviour?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So this is far from an answer, but discovered a few things that maybe will help you or others come up with a potential workaround.  Apologies if these are things you've already seen and noted.

First, it's not the call to TextBox2.Select() that's the problem per se. This for instance, works fine for me

```
    private void txt1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var start =  TextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var length = TextBox1.SelectionLength;
        TextBox2.Select(3, 5);
    }
```

unfortunately, using `start` and `length` versus the hard-coded 3 and 5, that is, the following, DOES NOT WORK:

```
    private void txt1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var start =  TextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var length = TextBox1.SelectionLength;
        TextBox2.Select(start, length);
    }
```

I also discovered that I could select TWO characters if I started from the end, but only one from the beginning.  That got me to thinking about dispatching the call to set the second selection:

```
    private void txt1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var start =  TextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var length = TextBox1.SelectionLength;
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, 
            () => TextBox2.Select(start, length));
    }
```

Now I can select 2 from the front and 3 and sometimes 4 from the back.  Took it a step further, and was able to select as many as six or seven with a really fast swipe.

```
    private void txt1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var start =  TextBox1.SelectionStart;
        var length = TextBox1.SelectionLength;
        Dispatcher.RunIdleAsync((v) => Highlight());
    }

    public void Highlight()
    {
        TextBox2.Select(TextBox1.SelectionStart, TextBox1.SelectionLength);
    }
```

Seems like the trick to working around this is not setting TextBox2 until whatever vestiges of the TextBox1 SelectionChanged event have completed.

This may be worth registering on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/intro/).

Answer (score 0):

Mine is only a partial solution as well.

I did some debugging and noticed that the `SelectionChanged` event is fired throughout the text selection process. In other words, a single finger "swipe" will generate multiple `SelectionChanged` events.

As you found out, calling `TextBox.Select` during a text selection gesture affects the gesture itself. Windows seems to stop the gesture after the programmatic text selection.

My workaround is to delay as long as possible calling the `TextBox.Select` method. This does work well, except for one edge case. Where this method fails is in the following scenario:

The user begins a select gesture, say selecting x characters. The user, without taking their finger off the screen, pauses for a second or two. The user then attempts to select more characters.

My solution does not handle the last bit in the above paragraph. The touch selection after the pause does not actually select anything because my code will have called the `TextBox.Select` method.

Here is the actual code. As I mentioned above, there are multiple selection changed events fired during a single selection gesture. My code uses a timer along with a counter to only do the programmatic selection when there are no longer any pending touch generated selection changed events.

```
int _selectCounter = 0;
const int SELECT_TIMER_LENGTH = 500;
async private void TextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // _selectCounter is the number of selection changed events that have fired.
    // If you are really paranoid, you will want to make sure that if
    // _selectCounter reaches MAX_INT, that you reset it to zero.
    int mySelectCount = ++_selectCounter;

    // start the timer and wait for it to finish
    await Task.Delay(SELECT_TIMER_LENGTH);

    // If equal (mySelectCount == _selectCounter),
    // this means that NO select change events have fired
    // during the delay call above. We only do the
    // programmatic selection when this is the case.
    // Feel free to adjust SELECT_TIMER_LENGTH to suit your needs.
    if (mySelectCount == _selectCounter)
    {
        this.TextBox2.Select(this.TextBox1.SelectionStart, this.TextBox1.SelectionLength);
    }
}
```